# Exclude namespaces from dotnet test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, command-line-interface, xunit

How can we exclude a specific namespace from `dotnet test`?

`dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName~Namespace.Here` works for including a namespace, but `!~` is not recognized for excluding a namespace.

Comment: You could try something like `FullyQualifiedName~Namespace1&FullyQualifiedName!=ExcludedTests` the operator `!~` is unfortunately [not supported](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-using-testcasefilter/)

Answer (score 5):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=mstest you need to escape the exclamation mark:

> Using filters that include exclamation mark ! on *nix requires escaping since ! is reserved.

So i guess you need to do:

```
dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName\!~Namespace.Here
```

Comment: Did not work for me : Netcore 7  + Linux

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so to elaborate on my half-assed comment:
As of now the `!~` operator is not supported ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests)).

If you want to exclude a specific namespace completely from your tests I think your best bet would be to work with test categories. It is a suboptimal work around for what you want to do in the first place, as it may lead to every test in your namespace have an additional category which just states that it's in this namespace.

But unfortunately as of right now there is no way to filter by namespaces except inclusions.

Comment: `Category!=` was my second try which also doesn't work.  Was trying to exclude all functional/integration tests in my unit test run as to avoid having to add a category or explicitly include all my unit test namespaces.  Looks like filter is set up to only include, not exclude at this time.

Comment: @Devon hm, im pretty sure `category!=x` works. Althoguh there might be a difference with xUnit and the traits. Do you get an error message like [here](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1314) (`Exception filtering tests: No tests matched the filter because it contains one or more properties that are not valid (Bug). Specify filter expression containing valid properties (DisplayName, FullyQualifiedName) and try again`)?

Comment: Yes, that's the error I receive, but Category= works strangely enough.

Comment: @Devon Seems like it was a problem in vstest (all the reports i find are from 2017-2018). So, you could try updating your Microsoft.Net.Test.SDK as suggested in the bug report if you are using an older version.